# Javascript LocalStorage Setting Other Variables to Null

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a program that calculates ticket quantities. If I set a new value to a variable using local storage it will cause the other variables to go null. But if I set the value of every variable in the form then nothing will be null and there are no issues, but the problem is I don't want the user to have to set the values of every variable everytime they want to set the value of one variable. How can I rewrite this code so that the other variables won't go to null if one variable is changed? Currently I only have it setup for beforenoonprice and matineeprice, but will add the rest once this issue is resolved.

```
var beforenoonprice = 6.75; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE BEFORE NOON TICKET
var matineeprice = 9.00; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE MATINEE TICKET
var seniorprice = 9.25; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE SENIOR TICKET
var militaryprice = 9.25; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE MILITARY TICKET
var studentdayprice = 8.00; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE STUDENT DAY TICKET
var seniordayprice = 6.75; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE SENIOR DAY TICKET
var adultprice = 10.75; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE ADULT TICKET
var childprice = 8.00; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE CHILD TICKET
var threeDprice = 3.50; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE REGULAR 3D PRICE
var imaxPrice = 4.50; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE IMAX TICKET
var imax3dPrice = 5.50; // CHANGE THE PRICE OF THE IMAX 3D TICKET
var output = document.getElementById('output');


function updatePricingFunction()
 {
var beforeNoonFieldChange = document.getElementById('beforeNoonNPSlot').value;
var matineeFieldChange = document.getElementById('matineeNPSlot').value;

localStorage.setItem('text', beforeNoonFieldChange);
localStorage.setItem('text1', matineeFieldChange);


 }

 function load(){
     var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
     var storedValue1 = localStorage.getItem('text1');

        beforenoonprice = storedValue;
         matineeprice = storedValue1;
          beforeNoonCPSlot.innerHTML = "$" + parseFloat(storedValue).toFixed(2);
        $("#beforeNoonPrice").attr = parseFloat(storedValue).toFixed(2);

$('#beforeNoonPrice').append("$" + (storedValue * 1).toFixed(2));

 matineeCPSlot.innerHTML = "$" + parseFloat(storedValue1).toFixed(2);
        $("#matineePrice").attr = parseFloat(storedValue1).toFixed(2);

$('#matineePrice').append("$" + (storedValue1 * 1).toFixed(2));

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in your code but understand that there's just no way that setting some local storage property to a value will affect other global variables. I think your interpretation of your observations is probably incorrect.

Comment: I created a JSBin, It looks a little messy using the site, but it's still functional. http://jsbin.com/hinogano/1/edit?html,css,js,output To Change prices click "Update Prices" and change one of the top two fields either before noon or matinee and click "Update Pricing" click cancel and then 
"run with js" to go back to main screen to test application.